# App crashes with error 'Could not execute method for android:onClick' when try to validate empty field

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

I tried to create empty field validation that if user don't put any String/Integer and just press on the button, he will recive popup stating that field is empty.

I would appriciate any help.

See my code below:

```
...

    public void clickCheck (View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userType);
        Integer userNum = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        String userField = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        String message = "";


        if (userField.isEmpty()) {
            message = "please input something!!!!!";
        } else {
            Shape mynumber = new Shape();
            mynumber.number = userNum;
            if ((mynumber.isSquareNum() == true) && (mynumber.isTriangularNum() == false)) {

                makeToast("The number " + userNum + " is a Square number.");
            } else if ((mynumber.isSquareNum() == false) && (mynumber.isTriangularNum() == true)) {
                makeToast("The number " + userNum + " is a Triangular number.");
            } else if ((mynumber.isSquareNum() == false) && (mynumber.isTriangularNum() == false)) {
                makeToast("The number " + userNum + " is a not Square or Triangular shape");
            } else if ((mynumber.isSquareNum() == true) && (mynumber.isTriangularNum() == true)) {
                makeToast("The number " + userNum + " is both Square & Triangular shapes");
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is related to

```
Integer userNum = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

it may throw **NumberFormatException** and you won't reach till validation.

you can try like this

```
    public void clickCheck (View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userType);
        String userField = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        String message = "";
        if (userField.isEmpty()) {
            message = "please input something!!!!!";
        } else {
            Shape mynumber = new Shape();
            Integer userNum;
            try {
                userNum = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                message = "Not an integer";
            }
            mynumber.number = userNum;
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i followed your suggestion but and now app not crashes but no response as well. after i click on the button i don't get any error or any Toast. Any suggestion?

Comment: can you show your button xml code as well?  do you have `android:onClick="clickCheck"`  there?

Comment: Do you mean this code? 
<Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="205dp" android:onClick="clickCheck" android:text="Check"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/userType" android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: can you show the content of makeToast function as well?

Comment: public void makeToast (String string){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hakob your suggestion worked very well.
My problem afterwared was beacuse my Toast command has not been defined correctly.

So i had this: message = "please input something!!!!!";

And i change to this:  makeToast("please input something!!!!!");

Actully i didn't defined Toast command at all so the app didn't understand it should popup a message :).

Thanks again for all the help.